# Start VLC and play webcam stream in C#

Tags: c#, webcam, vlc

i am trying to start the vlc media player (without including it) and play my webcam stream with an delay of 3 seconds.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = ":dshow-vdev=UV-3013XC_4102889504 :dshow-adev=  :live-caching=3000";
        p.Start();
```

With that, it starts the vlc player without any errors occuring. But it wont start playing the webstream. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i found the solution. One Argument was missing:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "dshow:// :dshow-vdev=UV-3013XC_4102889504 :dshow-adev=  :live-caching=3000";//Dateiname
        p.Start();//Prozess starten
```